# how to upload values as array using c# webclient ? eg items[]="foo" items[]="foo2"

Tags: c#, webclient

How would you upload a parameter that is an array using c# webclient ?

```
    public string CallWebService(string url, NameValueCollection parametres, string HttpVerb = "GET")
    {
        WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
        byte[] myresponse = myWebClient.UploadValues(url, HttpVerb, parametres);
        // on essaye de récuopérer l'encoding depuis les headers
        // sinon on utilise l'encoding par defaut           
        Encoding encoding;
        encoding = WebUtils.GetEncodingFrom(myWebClient.ResponseHeaders, Encoding.Default);
        return encoding.GetString(myresponse);
    }
CallWebService(url, new NameValueCollection {
            { "type_pj", "99_AU" },
            { "type_pj", "41_NC" },
            { "type_pj", "41_NC" }
}, "PATCH")
```

is not understood server side. It is seen as one string "99_AU,41_NC,41_NC".
If I use

```
CallWebService(url, new NameValueCollection {
            { "type_pj[]", "99_AU" },
            { "type_pj[]", "41_NC" },
            { "type_pj[]", "41_NC" }
}, "PATCH")
```

it is seen as an Array but it contains only one string ["99_AU,41_NC,41_NC"]

The following curl get its right.

```
curl -X PATCH \  https://... \  -d 'type_pj%5B%5D=99_AU&type_pj%5B%5D=41_NC&type_pj%5B%5D=41_NC'
```

The servers sees it as an array of 3 strings ["99_AU","41_NC","41_NC"]

How could I achieve the same using a webclient ?

**[EDIT]**

It looks like I confused System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection and  System.Web.HttpValueCollection (which is a NameValueCollection too but with additionnal features)

```
        var nv = new NameValueCollection {};
        nv.Add("type_pj[]", "99_AU");
        nv.Add("type_pj[]", "41_NC");
        nv.Add("withcomma", "text,with,comma");
        nv.Add("type_pj[]", "41_NC");
=> nv["type_pj[]"] = "99_AU,41_NC,41_NC" // = nv[0]
=> nv["withcomma"] = "text,with,comma" // = nv[1]

        var hv = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);
        hv.Add("type_pj[]", "99_AU");
        hv.Add("type_pj[]", "41_NC");
        hv.Add("withcomma", "text,with,comma");
        hv.Add("type_pj[]", "41_NC");
        string resp = hv.ToString();

=> hv["type_pj[]"] = "99_AU,41_NC,41_NC" // = hv[0]
=> hv["withcomma"] = "text,with,comma" // = hv[1]
```

In an HttpValueCollection, when you add a new value for an existing key it looks like it concatenate the new value ti the previous but under the hood it is also stored in a array.

```
=> hv.GetValues("type_pj[]") = ["99_AU","41_NC","41_NC"] // !!! Array of 3 strings
=> hv.GetValues("withcomma[]") = ["text,with,comma"] // !!! Array of 1 strings
```

The HttpValueCollection has a ToString() method that does the url encoding for you and it preserves the array struct !

```
=> hv.ToString() ="type_pj%5b%5d=99_AU&type_pj%5b%5d=41_NC&type_pj%5b%5d=41_NC&withcomma=text%2cwith%2ccomma"
```

So the best solution is probably to use uploadString as suggested by elgonzo. But instead of using Lis you could use an HttpValueCollection which ToString() method will take care of the urlencoding for you.

Comment: Too bad weblient uploadvalues doesn't directly acccept a HttpValueCollection too

Comment: `HttpValueCollection` is a type that is internal to the .NET class library. Without trickery involving reflection, you wouldn't be able to use it. But even if you were willing to do this trickery, `HttpValueCollection` derives from `NamedValueCollection`, so you would still be stuck with the very same problem anyway... ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are facing is due to using *NamedValueCollection*. If you inspect the content of your *NamedValueCollection* in the debugger, you will notice that it aggregates all values under just one key. This is because the name keys you feed to your *NamedValueCollection* are all identical.

To avoid this, you will have to generate the data payload string manually. To make things simple for the Linq Select statement below in my answer, i switch to a collection that does not organize key/value pairs depending on the uniqueness of the key. For example, you could use a list like this:

```
var parameters = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
{
    new KeyValuePair<string,string>("type_pj[]", "99_AU"),
    new KeyValuePair<string,string>("type_pj[]", "41_NC"),
    new KeyValuePair<string,string>("type_pj[]", "41_NC")
};
```

Based on this collection, you could then "manually" compose the data payload string while also making sure both names and values are properly escaped:

```
var dataPayload = string.Join(
    "&",
    parameters.Select(kvp => $"{Uri.EscapeDataString(kvp.Key)}={Uri.EscapeDataString(kvp.Value)}")
);
```

(There are certainly different ways and flavors of how to do this; my example here is just an illustration of the general approach.)

The last step missing is to actually send the encoded payload string and receive the server response. Based on the code in the question, you expect a server response that is text. Fortunately, *WebClient* has an upload method that both accepts the data to be uploaded as string as well as returning the server response as string: [`UploadString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.uploadstring). Depending on the particular expectations of your server, you might need to specify the content type explicitly, too.

```
var myWebClient = new WebClient();
myWebClient.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
string responseString = myWebClient.UploadString(url, "PATCH", dataPayload);
```

---

As pointed out by @frenchone in the comments, it is also possible to generate the encoded data payload string from a *NameValueCollection*, albeit with a slightly more complex Linq statement:

```
var parameters = NameValueCollection
{
    { "type_pj[]", "99_AU" },
    { "type_pj[]", "41_NC" },
    { "type_pj[]", "41_NC" }
}

var dataPayload = string.Join(
    "&",
    parameters.AllKeys.SelectMany(
        key => parameters.GetValues(key).Select(val => $"{Uri.EscapeDataString(key)}={Uri.EscapeDataString(val)}")
    )
);
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. System.Web.HttpValueCollection could be a better solution than your List of KeyValuePair because HttpValueCollection .ToString() already does the encoding for you so you don't need the dataPayload.

Comment: See my comment with regard to `HttpValueCollection` underneath your question. No, `HttpValueCollection` wouldn't solve anything with regard to your problem... :-(

Comment: I don't get it. var hv = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty); hv.Add("type_pj[]", "99_AU");... dataPayload = hv.ToString()... should fit just fine in your exemple. Unless parsing an empty string (to get the HttpValueCollection ) is what you call trickery ?

Comment: @frenchone Also, keep in mind that `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString` returns a `NamedValueCollection`. The actual type of the `NamedValueCollection` instance returned is just an undocumented implementation detail and might (or might not) change in future versions of whatever .NET platform you keep your program running. Writing code that relies on undocumented implementation details is not really a good idea in my book. But then again, you do you, and it is not my job to review or otherwise judge your code ;-)

Comment: It will help in the context of your solution because I don't need to do the payload manually and it would have helped in the webclient IF there was a test against HttpValueCollection type in the uploadValues (which is not the case for now)

Comment: OK I understood your POV

Comment: Damn, i eat a broomstick. HttpValueCollection differs in behavior from NamedValueCollection, despite inheriting from it. Weird thing...

Comment: @frenchone The trick with obtaining and populating a HttpValueCollection and then use its `ToString()` method to generate the data payload string is clever. I am reluctant to put this in my answer due to the undocumented behavior/type of the instance returned by `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString`, but it is really a clever - if a little dirty - idea. (Unfortunately, passing the HttpValueCollection to `WebClient.UploadValues` won't help, as the implementation of this method does not utilize HttpValueCollection's ToString method...)

Comment: I wrote rubbishes. GetValues(key) is in the NameValue Collection. So you can browse keys directly as flat string with commas or as Arrays. So with "just" a namevaluecollection the Webclient.UploadValues should be able to produce the right payload if it used the HttpValueCollection.ToString().

Comment: @frenchone, NameValueCollection.GetValues(key) would be a possible approach, but it also would kinda make the Linq query just a little bit more complex ;-) The reason why WebClient behaves the way it does can only be answered by the architects of this area of the .NET class libraries. For whatever reason they surmised and decided that a server would normally rather want to consume values aggregated by key. Who knows...

Comment: @frenchone, for what's worth, i have added the Linq statement based on a NameValueCollection to my answer...